# Как получить имя файла trace listener'a из app.config

Tags: c#

Привет ХэшКод. Подскажите пожалуйста как, с помощью ConfigurationManager (или еще чего нибудь), получить значение initializeData из app.config. Из такой секции :

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <clear/>
        <add name="fileListener" type="SomeFileListener" initializeData="D:\Logs\Log.txt"/>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте через `System.Reflection`:

```
var listener = Trace.Listeners["fileListener"];
var info = listener.GetType().GetField(
    "initializeData", 
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance); 
string path = (string)info.GetValue(listener);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все прекрасно работает.